# Error when added firebase packages in Flutter project

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, flutter, flutter-dependencies

My flutter app was working totally fine until i added **'firebase_auth: ^0.15.5+3'**- this dependency in my pubspec.yaml file. I am struck with this error:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on BLN L22 in debug mode...
[!] Your app isn't using AndroidX.
    To avoid potential build failures, you can quickly migrate your app by following the steps on (some google link here).
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
C:\Users\soham\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91 Error:
    Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:8:5-29:19 to override.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:8:5-29:19 to override.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.


BUILD FAILED in 2m 36s
AndroidX incompatibilities may have caused this build to fail. Please migrate your app to AndroidX. See (some google link here)
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I also tried changing minSdkVersion to 21 from 16, but din't worked.

(I'm new to flutter and android development)

Comment: What does flutter doctor give u?

Answer (score 0):

goto -> C:\Users\soham\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

inside **application** tag add **tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"**